# Django multiple apps and urls.py

Tags: django, url, routes

I have a site set up with Django framework. I would like the urls as part of this site to map as follows:

```
www.site.com                 -> main.html
www.site.com/                -> main.html
www.site.com/projects        -> projects.html
www.site.com/projects/       -> projects.html
www.site.com/projects/web    -> web.html
www.site.com/projects/web/   -> web.html
www.site.com/projects/mobile -> mobile.html
www.site.com/projects/mobile/-> mobile.html
www.site.com/projects/whatev -> 404.html
www.site.com/projects/whenev -> 404.html
www.site.com/projects/web/w  -> 404.html
```

I currently have the main site set up as a Django app with its own urls, and the projects portion of the site set up as its own app. The mapping is as follows:

**site/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', portfolio_views.about_page, name = "aboutPage"),
    url(r'^about$', portfolio_views.about_page, name = "aboutPage"),
    url(r'^experience$', portfolio_views.experience_page, name = "experiencePage"),
    url(r'^projects', include('projectsApp.urls')),
    url(r'^projects/', include('projectsApp.urls')),
    url(r'^publications$', portfolio_views.publications_page, name = "publicationsPage"),
    url(r'^qualifications$', portfolio_views.qualifications_page, name = "qualificationsPage"),
    url(r'^contact$',portfolio_views.contact_page, name="contactPage"),
    url(r'^submitted$', portfolio_views.contact_submitted_page, name = "submittedPage"),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

For the project app:

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.projects_page, name='projectPage'),#site/projects
        url(r'^web$',views.web_project, name='webProject') #site/projects/web
    ]
```

Currently the following urls yield:

```
www.site.com                 -> main.html
www.site.com/                -> main.html
www.site.com/whatever        -> 404.html (with css formatting)
www.site.com/projects        -> projects.html
www.site.com/projects/       -> projects.html (without css formatting)
www.site.com/projects/web    -> 404.html (without css formatting)
www.site.com/projects/web/   -> 404.html (without css formatting)
www.site.com/projects/web/whatev -> 404.html (without css formatting)
```

There are css formatting in /static/ dir within the site App.

I am not sure why, given my url pattern I am unable to get to /web from within the projects app. Inside my projects.html I have a link that refers to web.html as 'projects/web' that yields 404.html. Do I need to always link an absolute address outside of the main app? I.e. any files served in projects app as www.site.com/projects/link?

Answer (score 0):

Using `include` for urls without a slash (e.g. `r'^projects'`) is very unusual. It means that you are making content available at `/projectsweb` as well as `/projects/web`.

I would try removing the includes without a trailing slash from your url config.

Django will then redirect from urls without slashes to urls with slashes, as long as the [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#append-slash) setting is True and you have the common middleware installed. For example, it will redirect from `www.site.com/projects` to `www.site.com/projects/`.

This might fix your CSS formatting. If it doesn't, you'll have a simple URL config, so it will be easier to spot other problems.